# TabItem header loses Binding to Property="TextElement.Foreground"

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following `ControlTemplate` for `TabItem`

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="Border">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>\
```

works o.k. when I use it like

`<TabItem Header="Details">`,

but not any more when I use:

```
<TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock >
            <Run Text="Details " />
            <Run Text="{Binding ViewModel.ToFrom, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
 </TabItem.Header>
```

or

```
<TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Content="Test"/>
</TabItem.Header>
```

In also tried it in a simple test-project with the same result.
I can only add that
`<TabItem.Header>Test</TabItem.Header>`
also works.

This disappoints me. I tried to bind `TextBlock`somehow to the attached property `TextElement` without luck.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
And why does it not work like I expected?

Comment: You might want to change the TargetType to TextBlock in a different style as you are using a TextBlock inside the header.

Comment: I have tried your code and it is working fine from myside.. can you please show your viewmodel's code??

Comment: @VishalPrajapati I cannot show viewmodel's code. The `ViewModel.ToFrom` prop. is shown correctly only the `TextElement` props. are not picked up.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar The `ControlTemplate.Trigger` does not have a `TargetType`, only `TargetName`. Also using `Property="TextBlock.FontWeight"` doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure your binding of view with viewmodel is correct..If yes..also try applying DataContext = yourViewModelName in the constructor of your .xaml.cs file and try changing to Mode = TwoWay

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this;

Your Main Window.xaml file

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">

    <Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource MyTabItem}" >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Details " />
                    <Run  Text="{Binding ToFrom, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
        </TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Your MainWindow.xaml.cs file like this:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
 }
```

and your viewmodel be like this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string ToFrom { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        ToFrom = "test";
    }
}
```

This should work fine..

Comment: The issue is not related to databinding but to styles and triggers in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation could be that you have a default style for `TextBlock` which overrides the `Foreground` property. You could prevent using the default style when using an empty style explicitly.

Something like this eliminates a default style as source of your error, at least for debugging purposes:

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock Content="Test">
      <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style />
      </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock
</TabItem.Header>
```